# Ohmic load on AVR's SCK?

Tags: avr, isp

I have an ATTINY13, and almost all pins are used (only PB2 is free).

What I need to add is a controllable ohmic load, which I believe best way to add is with an N-channel MOSFET, similarly with this below circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdS7E9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I don't need anything fancy, load will not need to oscillate, it will mostly be off, and once it turn on, it will stay on for minutes/hour(s).

I have 2 concerns here, which I wish to address before putting this together for PCB manufacturing:

1. Is this simple MOSFET with these two resistors enough for controlling this load? (Note: load is real, I need to turn on this 180R exactly).
2. Main concern! As only PB2 is free, I'm worried about reprogramming this AVR, as PB2 is happened to be SCK.

Will this ohmic load ruin the ISP programming (MISO, MOSI, SCK, NRES), if the power supply is quite-well buffered with 100uF, 10uf and also 100nF caps right next to the AVR, so is this MOSFET *enough* for buffering the SCK line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this simple MOSFET with these two resistors enough for controlling this load? (Note: load is real, I need to turn on this 180R exactly).

Yes, simply select a MOSFET that will turn on with 5V Vgs. There are a lot of models to choose from.

However, your resistors are wrong: with R1=47k and R2=10k there will be less than 1V on the MOSFET gate. So you need a higher value pulldown, and a lower value gate resistor. For example R2=100k and R1=1k.

> Main concern! As only PB2 is free, I'm worried about reprogramming this AVR, as PB2 is happened to be SCK.

While programming the micro, SCK will be active, so you can expect your MOSFET to turn on and off, and the 180 ohm resistor will also receive power every time SCK goes high. If that's not a problem, then it's fine. This also applies to the other pins used during programming.

Comment: Yes, R1 I wanted to define as 1K. So in case my power supply will not collapse during turning on the load, I'll get fine with this buffering?

Comment: Sure, no problem. It would be a problem if your load was, say a heater, and turning it on in an uncontrolled manner during programming would overheat, for example.

Comment: Are R1 and R2 necessary at all? Isn't the charge/discharge current of the gate capacitance limited by the small capacitance and the driver impedance?

Comment: R1 is necessary otherwise the extra capacitance from the FET gate on SCK might screw up the signal when you program the mcu. R2, probably not.